# Can't connect to WPA2 Enterprise, Peap

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager

I am trying to connect to my apartment's wifi and it never connects. here is my syslog - http://paste.ubuntu.com/23279488/

Security is WPA & WPA2 Enterprise, Authentication is PEAP. I am not sure what my inner authentication should be so I left the dropbown on 'MSCHAPv2'.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, wpa_supplicant v2.4

Thank you!

Comment: At the router check the wireless encryption settings. Use WPA2-AES only. Not any WPA/WPA2 and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: @WildMan: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23282292/

Comment: @CelticWarrior: this a wifi for the building. i'll have to ask the management if they can provide me with the info.

Comment: The information you posted shows the wifi is turned off by the switch, it can be a physical switch or a key that turns it on.  Also shows a soft block please edit your question and post the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: I am not sure why but I am able to connect now.